# Aggettivo per esprimere il fatto che il cellulare non funziona più

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, vocabulary

Recentemente ho vissuto l'esperienza di dover passare alcuni giorni senza cellulare dovuto al fatto che non funzionava più. Non c'è stato verso di farlo funzionare di nuovo ed è finita che ho dovuto comprarmene uno nuovo.

Come potrei esprimere il fatto che il mio telefono non funziona più con un aggettivo?

- Il mio cellulare è guasto.
- Il mio cellulare è rotto.
- Il mio cellulare è scassato.
- Il mio cellulare è avariato.
- Altri?

Comment: Quello che mi dispiace davvero è che, nel mio vecchio cellulare avevo l'app di Stack Exchange, ma [adesso non esiste più](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353133/). Non l'usavo mai, ma mi ero abituata ad avere le notifiche di SE sul telefono. Erano veramente utili e ora mi mancano così tanto... :(

Comment: Sul mio cell (un iPhone) l’App di Stack Exchange c’è e funziona. Comunque il tuo cell  era rotto o guasto.

Comment: o forse difettoso.

Comment: Un'espressione molto colloquiale, oltre a quelle analizzate nelle risposte, è “Mi è morto il telefono” e sue varianti.

Comment: Il mio telefono è K.O. / kaputt 

Comment: @Hachi: Fino a pochi giorni fa, avevo l'app (per Android) e funzionava bene sul mio antico telefono. Il problema è che adesso non si trova più, quindi non posso installarla sul mio nuovo cellulare. Oggi, per esempio, ho avuto tutti questi commenti e risposte: mi ero abituata a sapere che avevo commenti e risposte (e anche ping sul chat) grazie alle notifiche dell'app. Ma oggi non me ne sono accorta fino a quando non sono entrata sul sito web di Italian.SE :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Userei *rotto* o *guasto*.
*Scassato* è informale e un po' forte se semplicemente non funziona: se dici che il cellulare è scassato me lo immagino in mille pezzi.
*Avariato* si usa principalmente per il cibo andato a male (*il cellulare è avariato* mi ha fatto sorridere però, puoi usarlo in tono ironico :) ).
*Difettoso* si usa se il tuo cellulare presentava già in origine un difetto, non se ha smesso di funzionare per altri motivi.

Answer (score 3):

Un oggetto *scassato* non è necessariamente non funzionante, potrebbe ancora andare, magari in modo altalenante difettoso casuale e così via.

Tuttavia, se dici “Scusa se non ho risposto, ma mi si è scassato il telefono”, il significato di guasto sarebbe chiaro.

Il cibo può essere *avariato*, cioè *andato a male*; una nave può essere *in avaria* e per traslato, anche un telefono, rappresentandolo fermo come una nave in attesa di riparazioni.
(Ho scoperto così che *avaria* viene dall’arabo.)

*Rotto* è l’aggettivo generico che si impara da bambini, quando qualsiasi giocattolo non vada come previsto è “lotto” (la erre si impara più avanti, di solito). Poi arriva la maestra e, anche giustamente, chiede di adoperare aggettivi più adatti, come “guasto”.

Personalmente, direi “il mio telefono è guasto/rotto” solo presentandomi al centro di assistenza. Altrimenti “ho il telefono rotto/guasto” oppure “mi si è guastato/rotto il telefono”.

In alternativa “il mio telefono è partito/andato” oppure “mi è partito/andato il telefono”.

Comment: “Ho scoperto così che avaria viene dall’arabo” ...e che dalla stessa radice deriva anche l'inglese _average_.

Comment: @DaG L'etimologia è spesso curiosa! Una delle mie storielle per gli studenti è che *zero* e *cifra* hanno la stessa etimologia (araba).

Comment: “Mi è partito/andato il telefono” o "il mio telefono è partito/andato" (non l'avevo mai sentito) è più o meno equivalente a "mi è morto il telefono" o "il mio telefono è morto"? Cioè, si tratta anche di espressioni colloquiale?

Comment: E di una nave si dice che "è in avaria" e non che "è avariata"?

Comment: Sì, sono espressioni colloquiali. E no, non si dice che una nave è avariata. Il cibo può essere avariato, le navi no.